# Is the property of  not containing $\mathbb{F}_2$ invariant under quasi-isometry?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Is the property of  not containing the free group on two generators invariant under quasi-isometry?  Amenability is, so if there is a counterexample it is also a solution to the von Neumann-Day problem (which of course already has a solution).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is a famous open problem. Akhmedov in MR2424177 claimed he could prove that the answer is "no". No proof exists, so I guess he discovered a gap in his argument.

Comment: Mark, is the supposed proof contained in that Thompson F preprint, or is it something separate?

Comment: @Yemon: That is separate. The paper MR2424177 (see MathSci) actually contains the claim, but proves a much weaker (still nice, though!) result where "free subgroups" are replaced by "free subsemigroups" or "no non-trivial law". He says that the "big example" will be in the sequel of that paper but the sequel never happened. 

Comment: @Mark: thank you for the information.

Comment: @YemonChoi do you know if that "or" can be taken for two separate statements, or for one; i.e. are "no free subsemigroups" QI-invariant and "no non-trivial law" QI-invariant, or is "no free subsemigroups and no non-trivial law" QI-invariant? (sorry for asking, I don't have access to the paper)

Comment: @ARG I'm afraid I never looked at the paper which Mark mentions, and I don't have immediate access to it although I can probably get hold of it through my university's VPN or similar if you need